# Access_Token refreshed while another thread is using it

Tags: box-api

I am using a global account to access my box from a web application, so it may happen that a user is uploading file for example which takes 10 minutes and on another thread another user was doing something and the token needs to be refreshed.

Is it valid until it expire? or also if it is refreshed even if it is not expired?

Comment: You included the Dropbox API tag in your question, but the Dropbox API never requires access token refreshes. Could you clarify what you need to know about the Dropbox API?

Comment: Sorry it was added by mistake.